# InvoiceNinja with Docker-compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, invoice-ninja

When I try to use the docker-compose.yml file from the GitHub page of InvoiceNinja, I get the following error. I have changed al the variables according to the Readme. Does anyone know what **causes this error**?

```
ERROR: for test_server_1  Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/***/test/config/caddy/Caddyfile\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f1454ea8eee1d6433ee4eda9a7cc313cbe2a2c54a6bb707d8edf9b95898772b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f1454ea8eee1d6433ee4eda9a7cc313cbe2a2c54a6bb707d8edf9b95898772b/merged/etc/caddy/Caddyfile\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for server  Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/****/test/config/caddy/Caddyfile\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f1454ea8eee1d6433ee4eda9a7cc313cbe2a2c54a6bb707d8edf9b95898772b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay/1f1454ea8eee1d6433ee4eda9a7cc313cbe2a2c54a6bb707d8edf9b95898772b/merged/etc/caddy/Caddyfile\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you did not clone the complete repository. We already discussed that in this [Github issue](https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles/issues/176#issuecomment-665696988).

Just for reference:

1. Create a new folder, e. g. `/home/test/my-new-in-setup`
2. Go to the new folder with `cd /home/test/my-new-in-setup` and clone this repository with `git clone https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles.git .`
3. Run docker-compose with `docker-compose up -d`